# Remove pie chart lines in illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have created a pie chart and colored it and all is looking good, however I am stuck with lines between each section and ideally I would like a solid color with no outline.  Been searching around and can't seem to find it anywhere.  Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve: http://vector.tutsplus.com/tutorials/designing/how-to-create-outstanding-modern-infographics/ Scroll down to step 15.  Thanks for any help, also I'm using illustrator CS5

Comment: Welcome to GD!  Can you post your result so far so we can see the difference between what you've achieved and what you're attempting to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the stroke colour to "nothing", represented in colour swatches by a red diagonal line.

Unless I've missed something?